# Maintain a local fork of a Public Git Repository

Tags: git, github

I have a local clone of a large public open source GitHub repository. I have made a few changes to the source code (across maybe a dozen files) and have compiled my own version.

I would like to remain in sync as new versions are released (as tags) on the public repo. My current workflow is to use `git pull githuburl.git <tag>` into the local main branch. I then go through and manually handle any merge conflicts. There are usually hundreds of changed files automatically staged by git (so individually it's hard for me to review every single one).

This seems to work but a few merge errors pop up where git doesn't successfully merge the changes. I then have to manually find the error during build and find where the merge failed. The *ideal* solution to my problem would be a git pull where all remote changes are kept *except* on that dozen or so files.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: You are doing it right... that's what downstream has to do. What I would advice you to do is to have a great set of tests that you could run when you merge to check that nothing broke.

Comment: Also, is there any reason you aren't proposing your changes to the upstream?

Comment: Perhaps the only comment to your workflow is that perhaps you should think about the merge in the other direction... not "I will bring my changes into my downstream branch" but rather "I will bring my downstream changes into their branch". That might make the reviewing process a little leaner if their changes are so big.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If you're implying propose my changes to the public repo for inclusion, nah, it's just personal changes that wouldn't be any benefit to the public repo. If you're implying what eftshift0 is in comment below yours, then the answer is because git is like hieroglyphics to me.

Comment: @eftshift0 Okay, that makes more sense, but how in the hell does that workflow work with my current setup. Sync main and then push branch changes to main? Git is, well, uh, not my strong suit.

Comment: :-) Say the upstream is "origin" and you want to pull from master. `git checkout origin/master; git merge -m "Merging my changes" my-branch`. When you feel like the merge is settled: `git branch -f my-branch; git checkout my-branch`. You could work with a temp branch as well, if that makes you more comfortable: `git checkout -b temp origin/master; git merge -m "My changes" my-branch; git checkout my-branch; git merge temp; git branch -d temp`

Comment: It might be easier with `git pull --rebase`. Depends on your use case.

Comment: @eftshift0 So that means I'll probably need to rebuild my repository since it's currently tied to a private github repository. My original idea was a separate private repo that I just pulled their changes in instead of pushing my changes to theirs. Way over my skis.

Comment: No no....you are not pushing into any repo there. You are working locally, the only thing is that you are merging in the opposite direction.

Comment: Just so that it is clear: insteaf of merging the upstream branch onto your branch, you are setting yourself on the upstream branch (**locally**, not really working in the branch of the repo) and merging your branch. Then I have instructions there to place your local branch on the result of the merge, no real operation is performed on any remote repo (or branch, actually.... when you checkout the remote branch, you actually start working on `detached HEAD`, so no real work on a branch).

Comment: @eftshift0 I understand the principles, but now trying to figure out how to keep it in sync locally with a tag and then merging my changes. That workflow is hard for me to grasp.